# Skrollr not fading links in div

Tags: skrollr

I'm using Skrollr across my portfolio for some text fading effects. All of my text is responding to the Skrollr data anchors with the exception of any link text wrapped in < a >. The < p > below, containing the < a >, fades in correctly, but < a > retains the default page styling. Any ideas on why and how i can fix it?

```
<div class="card" id="about">
      <div id="aboutwrapper" data-350="color:rgb(255,255,255);" 
       data-700="color:rgb(170,170,170);" data-1000="color:rgb(20,20,20);">
            <p>Blah blah blah blah</p>
            <p>blah blah blah blah <a href="www.blah.co">My Link Text</a> 
              blah blah blah </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `<a>` elements do not inherit color property of parent elements by-default. Try to add this line to your CSS: `a {color: inherit}`